# Extract top visited websites from logs

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

We are storing log data containing information about sites that has been visited from our network. I had like to query the top 10 visited websites. How can I achieve this with ElasticSearch? The index mapping is as follows:

```
{
    "data" : {
        "properties" : {
            "date": {
              "type" : "date",
              "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
            },
          "status": {"type" : "string"},
          "group": {"type" : "string"},
          "ip": {"type" : "ip"},
          "username":{"type" : "string"},
          "category":{"type" : "string"},
          "url":{"type" : "string"}
        }
    }
}
```

Sample Data:

```
"hits": {
      "total": 7,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "squid",
            "_type": "data",
            "_id": "AU_DT4_ibdcNyAnt753J",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "date": "2015-08-16T00:02:00.195Z",
               "status": "PASS",
               "group": "level3",
               "ip": "10.249.10.49",
               "username": "Hyder",
               "category": "ads",
               "url": "https://gmail.com/mail/u/0/#inbox"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "squid",
            "_type": "data",
            "_id": "AU_DMjDpbdcNyAnt75iB",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "date": "2015-08-15T00:01:00.195Z",
               "status": "BLOCK",
               "group": "level3",
               "ip": "10.249.10.51",
               "username": "Fary",
               "category": "ads",
               "url": "https://gmail.com/details/blabla"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "squid",
            "_type": "data",
            "_id": "AU_DT94kbdcNyAnt753Y",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "date": "2015-08-17T00:02:00.195Z",
               "status": "PASS",
               "group": "level3",
               "ip": "10.249.10.49",
               "username": "Hyder",
               "category": "news",
               "url": "http://aol.com"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "squid",
            "_type": "data",
            "_id": "AU_CwTEqbdcNyAnt74RJ",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "date": "2015-08-15T00:00:00.195Z",
               "status": "PASS",
               "group": "level3",
               "ip": "10.249.10.49",
               "username": "Hyder",
               "category": "Blog",
               "url": "http://gmail.com"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "squid",
            "_type": "data",
            "_id": "AU_DMmUQbdcNyAnt75iQ",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "date": "2015-08-15T00:02:00.195Z",
               "status": "PASS",
               "group": "level3",
               "ip": "10.249.10.51",
               "username": "Fary",
               "category": "ads",
               "url": "http://yahoo.com/vbfhghfgjfdgfd"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "squid",
            "_type": "data",
            "_id": "AU_DT1yjbdcNyAnt753B",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "date": "2015-08-16T00:02:00.195Z",
               "status": "REDIR",
               "group": "level3",
               "ip": "10.249.10.49",
               "username": "Hyder",
               "category": "ads",
               "url": "http://news.yahoo.com/"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "squid",
            "_type": "data",
            "_id": "AU_DMV1ObdcNyAnt75hd",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "date": "2015-08-15T00:01:00.195Z",
               "status": "BLOCK",
               "group": "level3",
               "ip": "10.249.10.50",
               "username": "Kamal",
               "category": "Blog",
               "url": "http://hotmail.com/dfdgfgfdg"
            }
         }
      ]
```

What I had like to have:

Top visited sites:

```
 - **Sites              -     Hits**

 - gmail.com - 3
 - yahoo.com - 2
 - hotmail.com - 1
 - aol.com - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to extract the base site ( Like gmail.com ) from the URL field before indexing and add it to a new field. Lets assume this new field is baseSite.
Then , you need to follow what is exactly told in [this blog](http://blog.qbox.io/elasticsearch-aggregation-custom-analyzer).

First make the field baseSite as not_analyzed and then do a terms aggregation on that field.